# Nop and Pipeline Hazards in this Assembly MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

After Compiling C to Assembly MIPS by Cross Compiler , i had:

```
main:
.frame $fp,32,$31 # vars= 16, regs= 1/0, args= 0, gp= 8

addiu $sp,$sp,-32
sw $fp,24($sp)
move $fp,$sp
li $2,5 # 0x5
sw $2,8($fp)
lw $2,8($fp)
nop
sw $2,16($fp)
li $2,5 # 0x5
lw $3,16($fp)
nop
beq $3,$2,$L4
nop

li $2,10 # 0xa
lw $3,16($fp)
nop
beq $3,$2,$L5
nop

li $2,1 # 0x1
lw $3,16($fp)
nop
beq $3,$2,$L3
nop

b $L7
nop

$L3:
lw $2,8($fp)
nop
addiu $2,$2,3
sw $2,8($fp)
b $L7
nop

$L4:
lw $2,8($fp)
nop
sll $2,$2,3
sw $2,8($fp)
b $L7
nop

$L5:
lw $2,8($fp)
nop
srl $2,$2,2
sw $2,8($fp)
$L7:
move $sp,$fp
lw $fp,24($sp)
addiu $sp,$sp,32
j $31
nop

.end main
```

I don't understand why there are many `nop` code lines, what is the meaning of `nop` in this code ? does it help anything in `Pipeline Hazards`? What if i remove all the nops ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOP`s were inserted due to pipeline hazards.

Recall that MIPS pipeline is composed of 5 stages: Fetch, Decode, eXecute, Memory, Write-back.

Let's go through some `NOP`s. The first one is:

```
lw $2,8($fp)
nop
sw $2,16($fp)
```

This code assumes there is no Memory-Memory forwarding. Why? Because if you draw a time-line pipeline diagram, you will see that the `NOP` is forcing `sw`'s Memory stage to occur exactly one cycle after the write-back stage on `lw`. Thus, the code assumes that the processor has Memory -> ALU forwarding, or Write-back -> Memory forwarding. Had we not used a `NOP` in between, `sw`'s Memory stage would read some garbage value from `$2` (whatever came from the decode stage), and the behavior would be undefined.

The second `nop`:

```
lw $3,16($fp)
nop
beq $3,$2,$L4
```

Here, `$3` is only available after `lw`'s Memory stage is finished. If we don't have a `NOP`, then `beq` eXecute stage would occur in the same cycle as `lw`'s Memory stage, which is not possible even with Memory -> ALU forwarding. Therefore, we have to delay `beq` for one cycle, and that's what `NOP` is doing. With this `NOP`, `beq`'s eXecute stage will occur one cycle after `lw`'s Memory. This works, assuming there is Memory -> ALU forwarding.

Similar reasons apply to the other cases, I suggest trying to figure them out by yourself.

Comment: I think the First one (`lw...nop...sw`) does have Memory-Forwarding, if it not, there will be 2 nop line (...nop...nop...) to avoid hazard.

Comment: @VAK There's Memory->ALU forwarding or Write-back->Memory forwarding, but not Memory->Memory. If there were Memory->Memory, we wouldn't need a NOP. With this NOP, we're placing `sw`'s Decode to happen on the same cycle as `lw`'s Memory (thus, maybe there's forwarding from Memory -> ALU, discarding the garbage read from Decode); it also places `sw`'s Memory in the same cycle as `lw`'s Write-back, so we can have Write-back->Memory forwarding as well. But we certainly don't have Memory->Memory, or if we do, the compiler is not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

according to your code all 'nop' instructions are added to fix the following error

1) branch delay

2) load delay

as these nop are added by compiler you can explicitly give an option to compiler to not add these nop instruction by  "set noreorder"  better I should give you reference to read . "See Mips Run 2nd Edition" page no. 288. And I don't see 'nop' is hazard barrier inst. as according to this book.